Gas Consumption Difference Between require and if Using error() in Solidity?
I'm developing a smart contract in Solidity and am interested in understanding which approach is more gas-efficient when using custom error handling with error().
I have two approaches to check a condition where amount should equal 1 * 10 ** decimals(). The first approach uses require with error(), and the second uses an if statement with error(). I’d like to understand which of these consumes less gas and, generally, which is more recommended for gas optimization.
Here’s the require example:
error OnlyOneTokenAllowed();

require(amount == 1 * 10**decimals(), OnlyOneTokenAllowed());

And here’s the if with error() example:
error OnlyOneTokenAllowed();

if (amount != 1 * 10**decimals()) {
    revert OnlyOneTokenAllowed();
}

My questions are:

Which of these two approaches consumes less gas in Solidity when using error()?
Are there any best practices or recommendations regarding the use of require with error() versus if with error() in terms of gas optimization?
Does one approach offer advantages in terms of readability and maintainability over the other?

If there are any resources or benchmarks that compare the gas usage between these two methods when using error(), I’d appreciate it. Thank you for any guidance!

Require will save some gas verses the if approach because in the require scenario in the case of a reversion, the caller is refunded the gas from the logical operation.  Basically whatever gas it takes to do if (amount != 1 * 10**decimals()) will always be consumed in the if case but not in the require case.  More info here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions
